# Ubuntu crashed after browser froze and I powered off. When I tried to reboot, everything was gone

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive, boot-partition, undelete

As I said, I was listening to a podcast, browser froze, computer froze, I powered off and when I tried to reboot, everything seemed to be gone. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

A couple other pieces of information that may be pertinent: I cancelled an update yesterday halfway through because if was taking a while and I needed to reboot my computer for another unrelated problem (printer issues). I never finished the update.

Also, I'm using a computer from a company system76 and the case is garbage. I've had problems over the years with the hinges breaking away from the case. Now, the entire left side of the case has broken and the screws have fallen out. The computer is still held together by many other screws, but the left side strains a bit when opening. I wouldn't think this would cause issues with the hardware, but who knows.

I'll attach photos of what I could manage to get up. I was able to get into the Setup Utility and take some photos, it seems like one of my partitions (the one with OS and everything else on it) is gone, but I don't know. I do have Ubuntu on a flash drive, i tried to run it, but it looked like it was going to put a fresh install on and I didn't want to risk deleting old stuff if it is still there somehow.

1. Boot up Screen message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWjrM.jpg ("Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key")
2. First clue that my hard drive disappeared somehow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rnZz.jpg
3. Boot options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQAut.jpg
4. Put Ubuntu flash drive in and this happened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdAKm.jpg
5. This is where I stopped because I didn't want to erase anything, even though i think it's all gone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4pXq.jpg

Thanks for any help you can give or light you can shed.

Comment: No, not all of it. Much is though. I'm actually going to open the laptop up, because, as i understand it, it isn't even showing that my main hard disk exists (unless i'm interpreting photos 2 and 5 incorrectly) and i'm wondering if it didn't get disconnected from the board somehow...

Comment: Are you sure? I'm supposed to have:
- 120 GB M.2 SSD   
- 1 TB 2.5″ 5400 RPM Drive

And I don't see the 120 GB SSD

Comment: I'm not really a super computer savvy person, sorry. I did mention that i thought my hard drive had disappeared in point #2.

Comment: No worries, 30 minutes on the wrong path isn't bad. Better than two days. And now you have an answer. Sorry that it's not a pleasant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your 120GB SSD with your OS on it seems to be completely dead.

- It's not detected by BIOS

You can try opening the case and re-seating the SSD.

However, if that doesn't work, then replace the hardware and reinstall Ubuntu onto it. Nothing more you can do. Dead SSD is dead.

- You have reached the limit of amateur effort. If you have truly valuable data on the SSD, you can pay for commercial data recovery.

Comment: Thanks. I tried reseating it and nothing happened, so i guess i'm screwed. I've only had this computer for a little over 3 years, what a damn shame.